# Parse XML file as it's written (no buffering)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I'm trying to parse an XML file as it's being written. I've set up a SAX parser to take the appropriate action for each element. The problem is that the XML file is written in chunks, and due to buffering (I think) the SAX parser does not always read and act on the latest chunk. This means that there can be data sitting the file that doesn't get processed until further data arrives. Is there a way to prevent this an ensure that the SAX parser always reads the latest data that is available? Or is there a better way to do this processing?

Below is the wrapper I am using to read the XML file as it is written. I did not see a better way to do this in Java, though I am open to suggestions. Note that the XML file may not exist when we start trying to read it, so we may have to wait for it to be created in this class.

```
public class XmlFileInputStream extends InputStream {
    private final File xmlFile;
    private InputStream stream;
    private boolean done;
    private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 100;

    public XmlFileInputStream(File xmlFile) {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
        this.stream = null;
        this.done = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (!getStream()) {
            return -1;
        }

        int c;
        try {
            while ((c = stream.read()) == -1 && !done) {
                Thread.sleep(POLL_INTERVAL);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return -1;
        }

        return c;
    }

    private boolean getStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (stream == null) {
            try {
                while (!xmlFile.exists() && !done) {
                    Thread.sleep(POLL_INTERVAL);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }

            try {
                stream = new new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // File deleted before we could open it
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void done() {
        this.done = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does stax help? It should work with streams. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the [Apache Commons Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) of use ? It'll watch for files and give you a callback as each line is added. It'll handle waiting for files to appear and subsequent deletions.

Comment: The tailer would help for monitoring the file, but the real issue is still that the SAX parser would stall when trying to buffer input that hasn't yet arrived

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on using the SAX parser directly. The InputStream interface was not designed for this kind of use. There is no way to signal that data has temporarily stopped arriving.

Instead, I read the file manually and when I detect a completed XML entity that I am interested in, I extract it and send just that to the SAX parser. This works fine for my purpose.